# NameError: name 'src' is not defined

Tags: rasterio

I am trying to clip a raster using a geoJSON without writing to my disk.

The following code compiles and produces the correct result.

```
import tempfile
import fiona
import rasterio
from rasterio.io import MemoryFile
import rasterio.mask
from scipy import stats

def getSummStats(raster, shapefile):
    #Open Polygon
    with fiona.open(shapefile, "r") as shapefile:
        shapes = [feature["geometry"] for feature in shapefile]
    
    #Clip the raster
    out_image, out_transform = rasterio.mask.mask(src, shapes, crop=True)
    out_meta = src.meta
    
    #Setup to save and write the clipped raster in memory
    with MemoryFile() as memfile:
        with memfile.open(driver = "GTiff", height = out_image.shape[1], width = out_image.shape[2], count=1, 
                          dtype=rasterio.float64, transform = out_transform) as dataset:
            #write the clipped raster to memory
            dataset.write(out_image)
            #read the clipped raster from memory
            ds = dataset.read()
            return stats.describe(ds, axis = None)    

with rasterio.open("B:/dd.weather.gc.ca/model_gem_global/15km/grib2/lat_lon/00/000/CMC_glb_TMP_TGL_2_latlon.15x.15_2020052500_P000_Copy.grib2") as src:
    print(getSummStats(src, "C:/Users/Tom/Downloads/canada_provinces/canada_provinces/canada_provinces.geojson"))
```

However, I would like to be able to call this script from the command line and input the raster and geoJSON when the script is called. I made some changes to accomplish this.

```
import tempfile
import fiona
import rasterio
from rasterio.io import MemoryFile
import rasterio.mask
from scipy import stats
import os, sys

def getSummStats(raster, geoJSON_path):
    #Open Polygon
    with fiona.open(geoJSON_path, "r") as shapefile:
        shapes = [feature["geometry"] for feature in shapefile]
    
    #Clip the raster
    out_image, out_transform = rasterio.mask.mask(src, shapes, crop=True)
    out_meta = src.meta
    
    #Setup to save and write the clipped raster in memory
    with MemoryFile() as memfile:
        with memfile.open(driver = "GTiff", height = out_image.shape[1], width = out_image.shape[2], count=1, 
                          dtype=rasterio.float64, transform = out_transform) as dataset:
            #write the clipped raster to memory
            dataset.write(out_image)
            #read the clipped raster from memory
            ds = dataset.read()
            return stats.describe(ds, axis = None)    

def main(raster_path, geoJSON_path):
    with rasterio.open(raster_path) as src:
        print(getSummStats(src, geoJSON_path))
        
if __name__ == '__main__':
    #
    # example run : $ Polygon_CMDVersion.py /<full-path>/<raster-name>.grib2 /<full-path>/<geoJSON-name>.geoJSON
    #
    if len( sys.argv ) < 2:
        print ("[ ERROR ] you must two args. 1) the full raster path and 2) the full geoJSON path")
        sys.exit( 1 )

    main(sys.argv[1], sys.argv[2])
```

However, this second method gives me the following error

```
File "C:\Users\Tom\Downloads\Polygon_CMDVersion.py" line 21, in getSummStats
out_image, out_transform = rasterio.mask.mask(src, shapes, crop=True)
NameError: name 'src' is not defined
```

If this helps, here is what I wrote in the command line

```
Polygon_CMDVersion.py B:/dd.weather.gc.ca/model_gem_global/15km/grib2/lat_lon/00/000/CMC_glb_TMP_TGL_2_latlon.15x.15_2020052500_P000_Copy.grib2 C:/Users/Tom/Downloads/canada_provinces/canada_provinces/canada_provinces.geoJSON
```

How can I resolve this issue?

Comment: what happens if you change the line: `def getSummStats(raster, geoJSON_path):` to 
`def getSummStats(src, geoJSON_path):` ?

Comment: The same error message still comes up

Comment: You haven't defined `src` in your `getSummStats` function, nor is it passed in as an argument. You have a `raster` arg but do not use it.

Comment: Yeah this was the answer. Can you post this as answer so I can accept it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The comment made by @user2856 was the correct answer:

You haven't defined `src` in your `getSummStats` function, nor is it passed in as an argument. You have a `raster` arg but do not use it.